# USB unlock silicon power enhanced storage

Tags: usb-storage

I have a silicon power USB flash . when i click for open it shows an error "the device need to be reset before it can be used"under a title "enhanced storage"
.now i want to format it but dosent work . just have unlock and set password choose on right click . who can help me ?

Answer (score -1):

Unlocking it might give you access to the drives file system in order to format it. Some companies used to do some odd things to USB jump drives in order to make data lockable. (Im looking at YOU Lexar). Im not familiar with your USB drives maker. the worst case might be that after you unlock it the drive will only allow you to access a large part of the drive (half or so of advertised capacity) rather than all of it. Either way you may as well unlock the drive to see what is there.